# Query reactions by issue number and user

Tags: graphql, github-api, github-graphql

Is there a way to query reactions filtering on issue number and user?

```
{
  repository(owner: "w3c", name: "webcomponents") {
    issue(number: 688) {
      title
      reactions(last: 100) {    <--- I want to filter on user here
        edges {
          node {
            user {
              login
            }
            content
            id
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the moment, but you can request this functionality by creating a new post [here](https://platform.github.community/c/graphql-api) and tagging the post as a `schema-request`.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately github graphql api doesn't provide this capability to query reactions by known user in this context.